# My try: statment isn't registering as an error when it should be in python

Tags: python-3.x, function, conditional-statements

I'm a super beginner here learning conditional logic, and I am trying to write a function that returns a simple true or false or error message.

My overall try statement is working and returns the answers I'm looking for when my arguments are the proper values, however, when it should be getting passed along to my except statement I'm am getting a 'False' instead. I am sure this is an easy fix, and my lack of knowledge overall is making it hard for me to know where to begin looking for answers.

```
#Function designed to give a 'true' if you should bring and umbrella and 'false' is not
#'true' if its sunny and chance of rain > .5, cloudy and chance of rain > .2, rainy
#'false' if else
def take_umbrella(weather, rain_chance):
  try:
    weather == 'sunny' or 'cloudy' or 'rainy'
    rain_chance <= 1.0
    return (weather == 'sunny' and rain_chance >= .5) or (weather == 'cloudy' and rain_chance >=.2) or (weather == 'rainy' and rain_chance <= 1)

 #I am stuck on why my print statement with the incorrect argument paremeters isn't 
 #triggering the except statement, instead it produces 'false'
 #p.s after many attemps, I'm not sure what to put after except either
  except weather != ('sunny' or 'cloudy' or 'rainy') and rain_chance > 1:
    return "{} must either be sunny, cloudy, or rainy AND {} must be an float equal to or less then 1".format(weather, rain_chance)

print(take_umbrella('overcast',2))
```

Comment: `if x != (a or b or c) ..` is incorrect. It's the same as `q = a or b or c; if x != q ..`, which should now appear trivially incorrect. There are duplicates of this, which comes up a good bit..

Comment: And it's really hard to find such duplicates :-/ Anyway, a Pythonic approach would be to use the `not in` operator instead: `x not in (a, b, c)`.

Comment: Those tests – even badly written and logically faulty – do not throw exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

I think, you don't have to use `except` statement, it's better to replace it with `if` statement:

```
def take_umbrella(weather, rain_chance):
    if weather != ('sunny' or 'cloudy' or 'rainy') and rain_chance > 1:
        return "{} must either be sunny, cloudy, or rainy AND {} must be an float equal to or less then 1".format(weather, rain_chance)
    else: # not necessary
        return (weather == 'sunny' and rain_chance >= .5) or (weather == 'cloudy' and rain_chance >=.2) or (weather == 'rainy' and rain_chance <= 1)
```

Also, I don't think, that these lines are useful in that way you wrote - there will be only the bool-type value, which you don't use anywhere:

```
weather == 'sunny' or 'cloudy' or 'rainy'
rain_chance <= 1.0
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're after here is an if-else statement instead of a try/except block:

```
def take_umbrella(weather, rain_chance):
    if rain_chance <= 1.0 and weather in ['sunny', 'cloudy', 'rainy']:
        return True
    else:
        return "{} must either be sunny, cloudy, or rainy AND {} must be an float equal to or less then 1".format(weather, rain_chance)

print(take_umbrella('overcast', 2))
```

That code will do what you want it to do. try/except blocks are used in a different manner. This is a simple example just do demonstrate it's usage:

```
x = "abc123"
for i in x:
    try:
        print(int(i))
    except ValueError:
        print(f"Failed to convert '{i}' into an integer!")
```

Output:

```
Failed to convert 'a' into an integer!
Failed to convert 'b' into an integer!
Failed to convert 'c' into an integer!
1
2
3
```

Without the try/except block capturing the `ValueError` that is raised by trying to do `int("a")` the program would've crashed entirely before it could iterate over the entire string.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks for explaining the use of try/except!